# I m stuck with jquery load with asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I m stuck with jquery load. this is my code .

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave()
var text = tinyMCE.get("texthtml").getContent();
var encodedText =  escape(text);
var idlerRaw = $("#cmb_movzu_ders option:selected").val();
var idler = idlerRaw.split(',');
var esasMovzuDers = idler[0];
var altMovzuDers = idler[1];
var fenn = $("#<%=cmb_fenn_list.ClientID  %> 
option:selected").val();
var sinif = $("#<%=cmb_sinif.ClientID  %>
option:selected").text();
$("#dersDialogYeni").load("yeniderselave.aspx?esasmovzukod=" + esasMovzuDers + 
                    "&altmovzukod=" + altMovzuDers + "&fenn=" + fenn + 
                    "&sinif=" + sinif + "&htmltext=" + encodedText);
```

In the yeniderselave.aspx I try to get variables like this

```
string htmltext = Request["htmltext"];
```

I can get other variables. but can not get texthtml.

How can I do that ? Thanks

Comment: well, you are requesting htmltext so here, `tinyMCE.get("htmltext").getContent()` I think so, i haven't use asp never ever but i think this is prob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the htmltext contains large amount of content, so it is not a good way..!!

The Querystring is limited to a few thousands of characters depending on the browser **(i.e. 2083 characters for IE).**

Use a `HTTP POST` instead and put the document in binary format in the body of the request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but its not about the caharacter count. Even if its length small i can not get it done. Because of when i encode the the text it look like "%3Cp%3Ethis%20is%20a%20test%3C/p%3E" .

Comment: Thanks. The problem was exactly as you say. Already solved . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `tinyMCE` is your control, then you have to use `tinyMCE.html()` to get the html of that control.

You can refer this link : [get HTML](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

It may helpful for you.